# python 2.6 print with formatting (%): remove newline

Tags: python

I use python 2.6 and have read many links about removing new line from 'print' but cannot find example of usage together with formating using modulo sign (%). In my program I am trying to write in a loop line of calculated data but each line data comes from different calculations:

```
while loop
    ... calulating value1 and value2
    print ('%10d %10s') % (value1, value2)    [1]
    ... calulating value3 and value4
    print ('%7s %15d') % (value3, value4)    [2]
    print #this is where newline should come from
```

So I would like to get:

```
value1 value2 value3 value4
value5 value6 value7 value8
...
```

Basically this approach keeps readability of my program (each real line has over 20 calculated positions). The opposite way would be to concatenate all data into one, long string but readability could be lost.
Is it possible to remove newline using "print () % ()" syntax as in [1] and [2] ?

Comment: Would the methods you've found work if you used [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of old style % formatting? I know at least the comma will, though I suspect that will work with % formatting. (You should still be using str.format though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a comma (`,`) at the end of the statement, the newline will be omitted:

```
print ('%10d %10s') % (value1, value2),
```

From http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print:

> A `'\n'` character is written at the end, unless the `print` statement ends with a comma. This is the only action if the statement contains just the keyword `print`.

Comment: To add `,` can't work in Python3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space#

Answer (score 1):

```
while loop
    ... calulating value1 and value2
    print '%10d %10s') % (value1, value2) , 
    ... calulating value3 and value4
    print ('%7s %15d') % (value3, value4) ,
    print #this is where newline should come from
```

Note `,` at the end of `prints`

Comment: I new about comma but was trying to add it between ) and %, Thanks :-)

Comment: You can also use `sys.stdout.write` instead of print. In this case you will write only that characters that you write

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without using `print`s trailing comma (or, with Py3/`from __future__ import print_function`, the `end` keyword argument), then you do have to do all your printing at once - ie:

```
while ...:
    # calulating value1 and value2
    # calulating value3 and value4
    print '%10d %10s %7s %15d' % (value1, value2, value3, value4)
```

If this makes readability an issue, consider putting the calculation logic into functions so that you can do:

```
while ...:
    value1 = calculate_value1()
    value2 = calculate_value2()
    value3 = calculate_value3()
    value4 = calculate_value4()
    print '%10d %10s %7s %15d' % (value1, value2, value3, value4)
```